# Semantically, must text which visually looks like a heading use h1-h6 tags?

Tags: html, seo, semantic-markup, html-heading

I have a page which contains a list of items as its content.

When no items exist, the design which I am to implement has a rather large heading reading something like:

> ### 'No results for this topic'

Now initially when I saw the design I instinctively wrapped the 'No results' text in a `<h2>` tag.

Afterwards I noticed that although I included meta content for title and description - Google displayed the 'no results' text as the title in search results - clearly not being the desired result.

Now on one hand I want to stick to semantic markup, but on the other I don't want it to mess up my SEO.

So my question is: Do I really need to use a `<h2>` element here for semantic markup?

True, the designer decided to display the text to look like a heading - but does this mean semantically that this is a heading?

Just for fun, I checked what Google does when you enter a search phrase with no results:

> Result:

The 'No results' isn't displayed like a heading and (hence) not within a `h1`-`h6` tag.

**Disclaimer**: I tried searching for an answer at W3C [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H42.html) and [here](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/h1,_h2,_h3,_h4,_h5,_and_h6) but that didn't really help me here.

---

**Edit:** I meant the 'No results' to be an example. Actually, I had similar cases where Google picked up other pieces of not-so-relevant text (which I had wrapped in a `<h2>` because of the design) as the title - even when the page contained many items.

Comment: “Semantic markup” questions are usually primarily opinion-based (and tend to lack well-defined *meaning*). This one does not even tell whether the text *is* actually a heading for something or not, and it seems to worry about Google, which is basically off-topic here.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela At the end of the day I want to know which html tag should be used. That's why I posted it here. There are many questions at SO regarding which tags should be used regarding semantics

Comment: But you haven’t even described what the context and the role of the text is, or what the criteria are.

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite follow. I included an example for the context, what didn't I explain?

Comment: A heading, if it is a heading, is a heading *for something*. It is absurd to discuss whether an individual phrase, with no context, should or should not be marked up as a heading.

Comment: Oh ok, sorry I get you now. Well yes, it is a heading because there are follow-up sentences regarding what the user can/should do and how to add content etc. But on the other hand in the context of the site and especially seo - this heading has little importance / relevance... only as far as *that section* goes - it is a heading.

Answer (score 1):

I think that such message shouldn't appear in h2 tag. But there are also other factors that determine what Google will display. All title, description and keywords should vary between pages but it also doesn't guarantee Google will use them.

In fact Google want to be smarter than we are. For one of my pages for English main page version Google used alt logo to display as page title although title is unique so now in Google it's displayed as `mainpage - logo` instead of normal title.

If I were you I would change "no results" from h2 to regular text for example p. You should also consider if you really need and should have indexed those pages at all.

Google "guidelines" change very often and they can even punish you if you have many subpages with in fact no content.

-- after editing question --

You should check first that your meta tags if they are unique on your page. It means searches (if it is indexes, pagination pages and so on). As I have written just before there is no guarantee that Google uses them at all. Google can use any part of your site and display it in search result as title or description.

Sitemap has no impact what Google indexes (or other search engines). It only help search engines faster index pages that are for example deep in structure. For sub-pages you don't want to be indexed you need to use in html head:

```
<meta name="Robots" content="noindex,nofollow" />
```

to stop indexing it by search engines that respect this rule (of course many crawlers / spam spiders don't respect it). After change it takes some time to deindex this page by Google. It depends of course on site size and how often Google spider is visiting your website.

Comment: +1 ,Thanks for this answer, and I think you're right that pages which don't currently have content shouldn't be indexed. (Not sure if I can control this however - except not to include these urls in the sitemap) However I'm after an answer which is a little more general... I updated my question to explain this a bit more.

Comment: I've added more info in answer

Comment: The problem is that the content is dynamic - users add the content so although today the page doesn't have content - tomorrow it might. So I'm not too sure about adding it to robots etc

Comment: Ok, but you create pages somehow. Users add content and then page is created, right? Or maybe it's rather something like mini-blog for each user and for default there is empty page but when user adds content it displays on that page and earlier there is info that nothing was found? But the main thing is still that you should not put not important messages in h2 in that case and should provide unique metatags for each page on your site.